# Confusing branches and L1-dcache-loads in the output of JMH's LinuxPerfNormProfiler

Tags: java, performance, perf, jmh

I'm measuring costs of busy-waiting implemented with two approaches:

```java
// 1
while(run) { // looping on volatile flag
}

// 2
while(run) { // looping on volatile flag
  Thread.onSpinWait();
}
```

Complete code of the examples is available on GitHub via [link1](https://github.com/stsypanov/sleep/blob/master/src/main/java/com/tsypanov/slp/plain/WhileTrueBenchmark.java) and [link2](https://github.com/stsypanov/sleep/blob/master/src/main/java/com/tsypanov/slp/plain/ThreadOnSpinWaitPlainBenchmark.java).
I'm running the benchmarks with `-prof perfnorm` and they yield:

```
Benchmark                                                        Mode  Cnt      Score      Error      Units
WhileTrueBenchmark.whileTrue                                     avgt   20   6460.700 ±  109.333      ns/op
WhileTrueBenchmark.whileTrue:CPI                                 avgt    4      0.444 ±    0.005  clks/insn
WhileTrueBenchmark.whileTrue:IPC                                 avgt    4      2.252 ±    0.026  insns/clk
WhileTrueBenchmark.whileTrue:L1-dcache-loads                     avgt    4  51523.529 ± 3556.009       #/op
WhileTrueBenchmark.whileTrue:branches                            avgt    4  13981.285 ±  958.249       #/op
WhileTrueBenchmark.whileTrue:cycles                              avgt    4  36407.576 ± 2434.292       #/op
WhileTrueBenchmark.whileTrue:instructions                        avgt    4  81985.523 ± 6300.983       #/op


ThreadOnSpinWaitPlainBenchmark.onSpinWait                        avgt   20   6463.334 ±   49.922      ns/op
ThreadOnSpinWaitPlainBenchmark.onSpinWait:CPI                    avgt    4      2.143 ±    0.056  clks/insn
ThreadOnSpinWaitPlainBenchmark.onSpinWait:IPC                    avgt    4      0.467 ±    0.012  insns/clk
ThreadOnSpinWaitPlainBenchmark.onSpinWait:L1-dcache-loads        avgt    4   7262.587 ±  324.600       #/op
ThreadOnSpinWaitPlainBenchmark.onSpinWait:branches               avgt    4   2951.111 ±  162.867       #/op
ThreadOnSpinWaitPlainBenchmark.onSpinWait:cycles                 avgt    4  36307.064 ± 1516.787       #/op
ThreadOnSpinWaitPlainBenchmark.onSpinWait:instructions           avgt    4  16943.396 ±  820.446       #/op
```

So from the output we see that for the same time elapsed we have the same cycle count, but `Thread.onSpinWait()` executed almost 5 times less instructions. This is understandable and expected behavior.

What is unexpected to me is that it produced much less `branches` and `L1-dcache-loads`. The benchmarked code doesn't have much branching and reads one and the same flag from memory.

So why are these two metrics (`branches` and `L1-dcache-loads`) so different?

Comment: Because the loop is executed much less times in the second case (with `PAUSE` instruction). What do you find strange, and what would you expect instead?

Comment: I expected at least number of branches to be the same as in the source code I have one `if` in both methods.

Comment: Can you put this as an answer so I could accept it?

Comment: I'm guessing you're on an AMD CPU, or an Intel before Skylake.  On Skylake, `pause` blocks the front-end for that logical core for about 100 cycles, up from 5.  The CPI/IPC numbers would be even more dramatic in that case.  (It waste less power spinning, and when the other logical core has any work to do, leaves more execution resources for it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On x86, `Thread.onSpinWait()` intrinsic is translated to the [`PAUSE`](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/cpp-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference/top/compiler-reference/intrinsics/intrinsics-for-sse2/miscellaneous-functions-and-intrinsics/pause-intrinsic.html) instruction. `PAUSE` delays the execution of the next instruction for an implementation-specific amount of time. Because of this delay, the second loop executes the less number of times comparing to the loop without `onSpinWait`.

Extra delay per each loop iteration => less number of iterations => less number of retired instructions (including `cmp` and `jne`) => less branches and memory loads.

Comment: Yup, TL:DR: if you check less often with a `pause` between each check, you'll do fewer total checks in the same wall-clock time before another thread changes the keep_running flag.